# Where I set the "ConfigureParameter" class to configure OracleByteArrayTypeMapping?

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core, ef-core-3.1

I need to configure a parameter from Oracle but I don't know where I set this configuration.

Where I set the "ConfigureParameter" class to configure OracleByteArrayTypeMapping?

The class is in the namespace:
Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Oracle.Storage.Internal.OracleByteArrayTypeMapping.ConfigureParameter

Comment: Show us what you have tried and be a bit more specific with some examples. This way you will get faster answers.

Comment: Hi, the class in question is part of the Oracle provider internal API, hence is not supposed / cannot be configured externally. May be you can provider more specific usage scenario of what are you trying to do.